# Including data from another server as part of a Rails response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app. I'd like to create a route that, in addition to doing some work in the controller and rendering a view, loads some data from another server to include as part of the response. Somewhat like a proxy, but with a bit of logic dependent on both the incoming request to rails and the data loaded from the other server.

Presumably, I'd issue some sort of HTTP request in the controller action, wait for a reply, and then make use of the result.

I'm interested in doing this entirely on the server — I do not want to use AJAX/CORS/etc on the client.

I'm curious as to whether there's a standard, somewhat official way of accomplishing this. I've seen a handful of examples using `net/http` — is this the "right" solution for the common case?

I'm not particularly worried about latencies, failure modes, asynchrony, streaming, or other advanced implementation details. Once I've got the basics down, then I'll happily layer in other fanciness to address any shortcomings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not at all interested in implementing it using jquery or cor, then I think you may like to chose `open-uri`.

`open("http://www.google.com").read` returns the whole site as string, then you can do the parsing.

If the site is returning json then parsing will be even easier:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def show
    json = JSON.parse(open("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXX").read)
    @name = json[:name]
    @email = json[:email]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work great for my needs. If anyone else is reading this answer, be sure to be mindful of the security implications: http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html